# Sequelize hasMany relation on two tables

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two tables

```
module.exports = function( sequelize , DataTypes ){
    var order = sequelize.define('prispevok',{
        id:{
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull:false,
            primaryKey:true,
            autoIncrement:true
        },
        Typ:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:false
        },
        hodnota:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:false
        },
        popis:{
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            allowNull:false
        }
    })
    return order;
}

module.exports = function( sequelize , DataTypes ){
    var shops = sequelize.define('sponzor',{
            id: {
                type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
                allowNull:false,
                primaryKey:true,
                autoIncrement:true
            },
            name:{
                type:DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull:false
            },
            address:{
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull:false
            },
            web:{
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull:false
            },
            uid:{
                type: DataTypes.STRING,
                allowNull:false
            },
            lat:{
                type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
                allowNull:true
            },
            lng:{
                type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
                allowNull:true
            }
    })
    return shops
}
```

first as

db.donation

second as

db.sponzor.

I want to achieve 1 : m relation , one sponzor can have multiples donations.

I used

```
db.sponzor.hasMany( db.donation , {as:'donations', foreignKey:'donations'});
```

but checking it inside sqlitebrowser it added column "donations" to donatio table, not vice versa, shouldn't it add this column into to sponzor table?

Also while it is 1:m relation, how should I add another donations inside it? 
Should I pass ID of it and it will create an array or what is the way to do it?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/associations/#one-to-many-associations

"Project.hasMany(User, {as: 'Workers'})
This will add the attribute projectId or project_id to User."

You should put the hasMany in the donation model.

"Also while it is 1:m relation , how should i add another donations inside it? Should i pass ID of it and it will create an array or what is the way to do it?"

you can do it using another alias and another foreingKey